# Can't save map from Lightning Component back to apex

Tags: apex, lightning, map

I'm truly stumped by this one.

I have a map of ContentVersion docs. 
The keys are: "Mine" and "Yours"
Depending on who is logged in, you can edit field values in the datatable that has "Mine" in it, and only view docs in the "Yours" datatable.

I can see the array (in a Proxy) when i console.log the output.
The problem is I cannot get the map of the edited docs to save back to apex.
When i check the debug logs, the array is always null.

```
COMPONENT
<aura:attribute name="myDocumentList" type="map" description="store documents list" />
<aura:attribute name="yourDocumentList" type="map" description="store documents list" />

CONTROLLER
Save: function(component, event, helper) {
    // call the saveContentVersion apex method for update inline edit fields update 
    var action = component.get("c.saveContentVersion");
    var theMap = component.get("v.myDocumentList");
    action.setParams({
        "values" : vals
        }
    );
    action.setCallback(this, function(result) {} );
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}

APEX CONTROLLER
@AuraEnabled
public static void saveContentVersion(Map<String, Object> values ) {
    System.debug(JSON.serialize(values));
}
```

Comment: I always assume case sensitivity in lightning - I'm not sure about this, but this `type="map"` I would normally always capitalize - `type="Map"`

Comment: Also, I normally just stringify the map/object when sending to the controller.

Comment: Just checking... the `vals` param... that's something you retrieve from the map, correct? (I'm assuming you've removed some code for brevity)

Comment: So in the map, you have: `{mine:[],yours:[]}`.... is that correct? And you are only saving `mine`? If that's the case, then you are send and array to the Apex Controller, not a map... you'll need to change that.

Comment: Caspar, thanks for the comments. I hear you regarding the case sensitivity.

Comment: Regarding the vals param, that is the portion of the map for key value "Mine"

Comment: Yes, I am only saving "Mine". Your comment is something i've wondered about.

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/288031/edit) the question to add detail of how "vals" is initialized.

Comment: Sprry Phil W, that's a typo. It should actually be "theMap"